# Glossaries header has more above space than other section headings

Tags: sectioning, glossaries

I'm using the glossaries package to manage the acronyms in my thesis.

Everything works fine except that there is some extra space between the glossaries heading and other section headings.

I stripped my code down, but the problem persists:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=3.0cm,top=2.0cm,right=2.0cm,bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[
nonumberlist,
nopostdot,
nogroupskip,
acronym,
toc,
section]
{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\newacronym{usd}{US-\$}{United States Dollar}

\glsaddall\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations},toctitle={List of Abbreviations}]

\pagebreak

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

I am using TeXShop on Mac and am compiling with pdflatexmk.

Thank you very much in advance!

Best
Patrick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\glsaddall` is adding the vertical space. If you use this command on a different page, the section headings come out correctly:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=3.0cm,top=2.0cm,right=2.0cm,bottom=2.0cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[
nonumberlist,
nopostdot,
nogroupskip,
acronym,
toc,
nomain,
section]
{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{usd}{US-\$}{United States Dollar}

\begin{document}

  something
  \glsaddall\clearpage

  \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations},toctitle={List of Abbreviations}]

  \clearpage
  \section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image: correctly positioned section headings]

Comment: Damn, you were quicker! ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer :( ?

Comment: I wanted to answer it as well and I was just preparing the paste when your answer appeared. Basically the same as I've done.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry :(. I didn't actually know what the problem was when I saw the question and I was just curious to find out, since I use this package, too.

Comment: @NFX: Yes, of course it works, it's the correct solution. Please consider to accept cfr's answer then

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I did now. I wasn't aware of that feature. But quite snippy you are ;-) Thanks again.

Comment: @NFX: I am not snippy :D The point is that new users often to forget to `say thank` you, i.e. accepting the answer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer All right, won't forget it next time :-)

Comment: @NFX There may be a translation issue - not in terms of what is being said, but in terms of the tone or how it is said. Using 'Yes, of course...' in this context may not have the same connotations when said in German as it does in English! Add to that the general problem of saying things online, without the different intonations which we use to fine-tune meaning, and you can imagine how thing might go...;)